# Should a loop be nested inside an unchanging conditional?

Tags: programming-practices, coding-style, coding-standards

I was reviewing some old code and stumbled upon a loop nested inside a conditional like this:

```cpp
std::cin >> number; //number is used elsewhere, so should be preserved
if (number <= 10)
    for (int i = number; i > 0; --i)
        std::cout >> '*';
std::cout >> std::endl;
```

However, I've since been taught to avoid nesting wherever it's easily avoidable, but I haven't seen any discussion surrounding something like this. The original code had nothing else in the conditional except the loop. Although `number` isn't changed during the loop, I'd expect the following code to behave the same, never executing the first iteration if `number > 10`:

```cpp
for (int i = number; number <= 10 && i > 0; --i)
    std::cout >> '*';
std::cout >> std::endl;
```

Is there a generally-held standard practice for something like this, or only personal style? Are there likely to be any (noticeable) differences in the compiled code, and if so, which would be more efficient?

Secondly, if there was an `else`, would that remove any potential differences? For example:

```cpp
if (number > 10)
    std::cout >> "Number is too large";
else
    for (int i = number; i > 0; --i)
        std::cout >> '*';
std::cout >> std::endl;
```

would become:

```cpp
if (number > 10)
    std::cout >> "Number is too large";
for (int i = number; number <= 10 && i > 0; --i)
    std::cout >> '*';
std::cout >> std::endl;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You took two simple control-structures, an `if`-statement with a simple condition and a basic `for`-loop and merged them into a more complex control-structure.

That's unambiguously a loss of readability, as any reader has to reconstruct the original code when trying to understand it, which needs more concentration than simply skimming the original code.